# PHP - Problem on validating empty form field

Tags: php, html, forms, input, field

I have a simple form that contains three inputs: name, message and email.

On the server side, I validate all these fields, however, I'm strugling to validate the name field. If I leave the input blank or start writing with a space (single, double, or more) and hit on submit, my php code is accepting this name as valid (where it should not).

Does someone knows how to prevent this?

Heres my code:

Page 1 - the form:

```
<form action="enviar-email.php" method="POST" name="emailform">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="nome"  placeholder="Type your name here" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                < input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Youre@email.com here">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="300" id="message" name="mensagem" placeholder="write your message" ></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn btn-special" onclick="alert('Thanks!')" >

            </div>
</form>
```

Page 2 - PHP page where I validate the fields.

```
if(isset($_POST['nome'])){ $nome = $_POST['nome']; }
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ $email = $_POST['email']; } 
if(isset($_POST['mensagem'])){ $message = $_POST['mensagem']; }

// blank fields or name that start with space are not getting caught by this if
if(isset($nome) && trim($nome) !== ""){
    Header("location:contato.php");

}
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$nome)) {
    Header("location:contato.php");
}
```

Comment: `div class="form-group">` < that is missing a `<` at the  beginning of it.

Comment: `if(isset($nome) && trim($nome) !== "")` - Why are you rechecking if it's set?

Comment: Have you tried adding `empty` check ? [PHP empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: `if(empty(trim($var))){ ..varaible is empty.. }`

Comment: I re-read your code... is `if(isset($nome) && trim($nome) !== "")` supposed to detect blanks? It seems so from the comment above that line, but it's doing the exact opposite. This condition will be met only if name is not blank.

Comment: Thanks for your message @El_Vanja. I didn't noticed about the !==, now that I changed it is working well enough, the only problem is that it still acepts a blank field, for all other cases it works well. So far, the solution is: if(isset($nome) && trim($nome) == "")

Comment: Well, then the problem should be elsewhere. The condition is correct for catching blank and whitespace-filled fields. What does `contato.php` do?

Comment: contato.php is the same page as the form page, with an additional text asking to fill the fields correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this -

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; }
```